# Databinding: Android Studio not recognizing view model class as type value (cannot resolve symbol issue)

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding

I am trying to get data binding working, but it's such a hustle. Just can't seem to get my view model connected to my layout file.
In my layout file under my  tag i reference to my viewModel this way:

```
  <data>

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.xxx.xxx.controller.mvvm.DashBoardResultsViewModel" />

</data>
```

But somehow I am unable to compile my project. My IDE keeps telling me 'cannot resolve symbol ....DashBoardResultsViewModel' even though the class is there.

The packagename and classname is correct.

No matter what I do: clean, rebuild project. Invalidate cache & restart... The classname is not recognized.

Running Android Studio 3.1.2. Databinding is set to true in all my modules.

Help!:)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that databinding was placing the auto generated files in the wrong module and thus couldn't find the class.

I removed databinding is true from the other module, which got my project to eventually compile and run again... though this is obviously not how you want to solve this problem. Seems to be a bug in the databinding framework?

In my xml layout file I am still getting the 'cannot resolve' error notification on my reference to my viewmodel class, but my project compiles and runs non the less.

Answer (score 0):

I just made my Data members public, and Now it's working

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding the

```
@Keep
```

annotation to my ViewModel

ex:

```
@Keep
class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {
    // TODO: Implement the ViewModel
}
```